# Please help identify this signature and seal

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, characters, character-identification

I have 2 art sketches my grandfather brought home from WW2. I think the signature is Chinese and would like to know if this is true and what it says. I’d be  grateful for any help. [image]

Comment: Both the writing and the seal read 靜湖 /Jìng hú/ Silent lake

Comment: Many thanks. Is it a signature or name of a place ?

Comment: The name of a painting is never put on a seal. I am sure 靜湖 is the  author's name

Answer (score 2):

The following URL

https://ukiyo-e.org/artist/seiko

lists many paintings with the same signature.

[image]